# unable to acquire token for tenant organization when running powershell scripts in azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to connect to azure portal from powershell. I am unable to connect. Following is the error message.
Connect-AzAccount : The default context can no longer be found; please run 'Get-AzContext -ListAvailable' to see all available contexts, 'Select-AzContext' to select a new default
context, or 'Connect-AzAccount' to login with a new account.
At line:1 char:1

- Connect-AzAccount
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
  ```

DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Connect-AzAccount; IsSuccess - False; Duration - 00:00:00.0390377;; Exception - System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: The defa
ult context can no longer be found; please run 'Get-AzContext -ListAvailable' to see all available contexts, 'Select-AzContext' to select a new default context, or 'Connect-AzAccount
' to login with a new account.
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Models.AzureRmProfile.get_DefaultContext()
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient..ctor(IProfileOperations profile)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Common.AzureContextModificationCmdlet.ModifyContext(Action`2 contextAction) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.SetContextWithOverwritePrompt(Action`3 setContextAction)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord();
DEBUG: Finish sending metric.
DEBUG: 8:08:57 PM - ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand end processing.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. You should also post your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try Running

```
Clear-AzContext
```

If you encounter the issue again, manually remove the files `.Azure\AzureRMContext.json` and `.Azure\AzureRmContextSettings.json`

If windows , you will find the above folder/files in `c:\users\yourname\` or if it is Linux  `/home/yourname/`